# Android app crash: Why there is (Unknown Source) instead of line number

Tags: android, android-proguard

My app that I built and signed to publish crashes occasionally on my machine, in the logcat I open the stacktrace for a null pointer exception.. But I am not able locate exact line numbers ? because it say (Unknown Source) 
for example some lines look like this

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at   me.com.myapplication.a.i.d(Unknown Source)
   at   me.com.myapplication.MainActivity.onResume(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1210)
```

As you see where-ever there is my application package I see no line numbers instead it says Unknown Source.

Here is my gradle config for this project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "me.com.myappliaction"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 6
    versionName "2.0"
}

signingConfigs {
    signed {
        storeFile file('../keystore/my.keystore')
        storePassword 'xxxxxx'
        keyAlias 'xxxxx'
        keyPassword 'xxxxxx'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    signed {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.signed
    }

}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile project(':mycomponent')
}
```

The app was using signed build variant. 
I used proguard command to read the trace properly using following syntax

```
retrace.bat|retrace.sh [-verbose] mapping.txt [<stacktrace_file>]
```

after this class names are shown better but still no line numbers ? I am wondering what exactly is wrong here that causes line numbers to be missing ?? How can I get trace that shows line numbers in my code and still be able to make it ready for publishing ?

Comment: Have you tried running the app in debug mode and do whatever to repeat the error? You get Unknown source because the code is obfuscated and minimized

Comment: Can't reproduce in debug yet, But is the retrace command that I used not meant to do the opposite and show the exact lines ?

Comment: That is how you deobfuscate, yes, however, I'm not sure that picks up line numbers because the code is still minified. Are you getting this trace from the developer console?  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281

Comment: No, not from dev console, its crashed on my device so I picked up the stack trace from the logcat copied in a text file and then tried to retrace. I removed the three lines   debuggable false, minifyEnabled true and      proguardFiles and then inserted a fake crash then it shows the line numbers but with proguard and minify etc it does not show the line numbers.

Comment: Right, and that makes sense because it's no longer minified and obfuscated

Answer (score 8):

In order to retain debug information after ProGuard builds, you need to add the following configuration (to your proguard-rules.pro file):

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
# rename the source files to something meaningless, but it must be retained
-renamesourcefileattribute ''
```

Comment: Instead of the empty string, one can just use `SourceFile`, to retain the file's name:
`-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile`

Answer (score 6):

This error will occur when you have enabled minify in **build.gradle**.

```
minifyEnabled true
```

To get the line number while using proguard, you have to write following line inside **proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

You also could upload the mapping.txt file to your Google Play Developer Console. On the console just click on the app you want to deobfuscate. Then go to "Android vitals" > "ANRs & Crashes":

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=[YOUR-DEV_ID]#DeobfuscationMappingFilesPlace:p=[your.app.package]

and upload the mapping.txt file that fits the current version of your app.

Location of mapping.txt:

**Android Studio:**

> \[YOUR-PROJECT-DIR]\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt

**Eclipse:**

> \[ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE]\[YOUR-PROJECT-DIR]\proguard\mapping.txt

Beware: Errors are deobfuscated only AFTER the upload of the mapping.txt. There is no deobfuscation of already reported crashes in the Google Play Developer Console.